# Replace a string between regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, sed, character-replacement

I have a csv file with the following contents:

`INTERB-MNT,2008-09-10T21:05:38Z,2008-09-10T21:05:38Z,MARIA`

How can I use `sed` to replace the characters `'T'` and `'Z'`, such that the contents of the file are changed to the following?:

`INTERB-MNT,2008-09-10,21:05:38,UTC,2008-09-10,21:05:38,UTC,MARIA`

I tried the following, but obviously I'm missing something because that does not produce the desired results:

`sed -e 's/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.T.[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}Z/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2},[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}UTC/g'`

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})Z/\1,\2,UTC/g'`

Answer (score 0):

To keep your text after substitution, you have to capture input with parens, and then use `\1` through `\9` to refer to the captured matching in the substitution part. To be able to use `\1` through `\9` backreferences, you have to use `-E` or `-r` options.

The command will look like this:

```
sed -r 's/(.+)T(.+)Z/\1,\2,UTC/g'
```

But this can't be used: the `T` will match the last part of the string because `(.+)` is greedy. So your idea to match `2008-09-10` and `21:05:38` pattern is good. You ended up with this:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})Z/\1,\2,UTC/g'
```

This works. You could also use this simpler command:

```
sed -r 's/(....-..-..)T(..:..:..)Z/\1,\2,UTC/g'
```

It is easier to read and write, and a false positive is very unlikely. It depends on your needs.

Comment: You do not have to use specific options to use a regex with *sed*, and the first `.+`/(.+)T(.+)Z/` won't match the first `T`, it will match the last `T` because `+` is greedy.

Comment: I tried without `\-r` at first, but got the following error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 24: invalid reference \2 on 's' command's RHS`, that's why I added `-r` to the command. About the other remark, you are totally right, I'll update the answer.

Comment: That is because backreferences are working with the advanced ERE syntax, without any `-r` or `-E`, BRE regex syntax is accepted. You always use a regex with sed.